# ¿Cómo puedo evaluar una ecuación de primer grado que contenga paréntesis?

Tags: python

Trato de evaluar una ecuación con paréntesis de primer orden para poder obtener el resultado.

En esta ecuación contiene determinados números y una variable x.

```
fmts = (
  '-{}x - (-{} - x) = {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}',

)
```

En la tupla anterior manualmente creo todas las posibles combinaciones de dicha ecuación.
Con eso me aseguro que se puedan obtener correctamente dichas ecuaciones.

Creo las expresiones reguales con las variables aleatorias que van a tomar un número random:

```
w,x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)
expr = choice(fmts).format(w,x,y,z)
```

Pero no puedo evaluarla por que no sé como hacerlo. He intentado con sympy, pero no me ha funcionado.
Intenté con `print(f"{expr} = {eval(expr)}")`, pero evidentemente no funciona. ¿Alguien tiene alguna forma de poder evaluar este tipo de ecuaciones? De antemano muchas gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias a tu pregunta anterior me motivé a hacer un módulo que pueda evaluar distintas expresiones (no solo exponentes) pero aún no he implementado la precedencia con signos de agrupación :/

Comment: No se te ocurre nada para este caso? :P

Comment: esperame un momento

Comment: Está bien ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Jefe, tendrás que esperas un poquito más, la parte literal de los números me dan algunos problemas. Bueno ya es hora de dormir, mañana seguiré trabajando, hasta luego!

Comment: jajajajajaja no pasa nada, una disculpa por presionarte

Comment: No pasa nada, esto me distrae y me alegra poder ayudar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133093/discussion-between-christian-and-ulises-antonio-chavez).

Comment: Solicite acceso al archivo, no pude hacer comentarios en el chat, pues no encuentro la opción para comentar

Comment: jeje ok, pensé que lo había puesto púbico. Y trata de ingresar al chat mediante el enlace de aquí de los comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente aún no he logrado implementar las variables en mi programa que puede evaluar expresiones aritméticas.

Con lo que hemos hablado por el chat me dices que haz cambiado la estructura de la variable `fmts` que ahora es un diccionario:

```py
fmts = {'-{}x - (-{} - 1x) = {}' : '-{}x - (-{} - 1x) - {}'}
```

Para este caso la forma en que se escogería de forma aleatoria la operación cambiaría, pues ahora debemos de escoger alguna operación del valor de una clave del diccionario, el `choice` quedaría así:

```py
view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)

#almacenamos la expresión para ser evaluada con sympy
expr = expr.format(x,y,z)
#almacenaremos la expresión en forma de igualdad
view_expr = view_expr.format(x,y,z)
```

Luego me he dado cuenta que usas otras funciones de `sympy` por ejemplo `Eq` que evalúa una expresión hecha con código pyhon. Sin embargo no queremos tener que escribir nosotros mismo la operación, sino que esta dependa de lo que se haya elegido anteriormente, por ello se me ocurrió usar un pequeño truco* (matenme por usar `eval`).

Debido `Eq` no acepta un string se me ocurrió usar `eval` para poder evaluar el string resultante del `choice`, pero la expresión algebraica está escrita de forma `ax+c+x=d` y python no puede analizar esta cadena con `eval` así que recurrimos a expresarla de la segunda forma que es mas descriptiva visualmente `a*x + c + 1*x = d` (colocamos un `1` como coeficiente de `x` debido a qu)e posteriormente reemplazaremos `x` por `*x` para que python entienda pero causará error de sintaxis para casos como `x+1` ya que será reemplazado por `*x+1` y eso es error de sintaxis, por ello agregamos coeficiente a las variables que estan solas para que no causen error.

```py
#reemplazamos por una multiplicación
expr = expr.replace("x","*x")
x = symbols('x')

#evaluamos
eq1 = Eq(eval(expr,{"x":x}), 0)
sol = solve(expr)
print(view_expr)
```

A `eval` se le puede pasar como parámetro un diccionario de variable, por lo que en este caso le pasamos un diccionario que contiene el valor de la letra `x` para que cuando encuentre dicha variable python la reemplace por la variable `x` de generada por `symbols`.

Esto imprime (en mi ejecución):

```
-18x - (-5 - 1x) = 24
```

Recordemos que en cada ejecución el resultado será diferente :D.

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian, aún así, hiciste un excelente trabajo

Answer (score 1):

Aquí dejo el código como lo quería hacer (propiamente para lo que necesito).
Lo único que hace es imprimir la ecuación y el resultado. Nada más.

Si quieren más detalles, revisen la respuesta de Christian, o si quieren aún más detalles, revisen el chat donde realizamos más comentarios. Todo el crédito es de Christian, pero reitero, escribo el código como yo lo utilicé. Saludos!

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
from random import randint, choice


fmts = {


  '-{}x - (-{} - x) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-{} - x) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-{} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} - x) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-{} - x) + {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-{} + x) + {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = -{}' : '-{}*x - ({} + x) + {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = -{}' : '-{}*x + ({} + x) + {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = -{}' : '{}*x + ({} + x) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '{}*x + {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-x - {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (-x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - (x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x + (x + {}) + {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = -{}' : '{}*x + (x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = -{}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) + {}',
  '{}x + {} = {}x + {}' : '{}*x + {} - {}*x + {}',
  '{}x + {} = {}x - {}' : '{}*x + {} - {}*x - {}',
  '{}x + {} = -{}x - {}' : '{}*x + {} + {}*x - {}',
  '{}x - {} = -{}x - {}' : '{}*x - {} + {}*x - {}',
  '{}x - {} = {}x + {}' : '{}*x - {} - {}*x + {}',
  '-{}x - {} = {}x - {}' : '-{}*x - {} - {}*x - {}',
  '-{}x + {} = {}x - {}' : '-{}*x + {} - {}*x - {}',
  '-{}x + {} = {}x + {}' : '-{}*x + {} - {}*x + {}',
  '-{}x - {} = {}x + {}' : '-{}*x - {} - {}*x + {}',
  '-{}x - {} = -{}x + {}' : '-{}*x - {} + {}*x + {}',
  '-{}({}x + {}) + {}(-{}x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*({}*x + {}) + {}*(-{}*x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-{} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-{} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x - ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '-{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '{}x + ({} + x) = {}' : '{}*x + ({} + x) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '{}x + (x + {}) = {}' : '{}*x + (x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x - {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x - {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(-x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(-x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x - {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x - {}*(x + {}) - {}',
  '-{}x + {}(x + {}) = {}' : '-{}*x + {}*(x + {}) - {}'

  }

a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)

view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
expr = expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)
view_expr = view_expr.format(a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z)

x = symbols('x')

eq1 = Eq(eval(expr,{"x":x}), 0)
sol = solve(expr)
try:
  print(view_expr)

  raw_expr = expr

  eq1 = Eq(eval(expr,{"x":x}), 0)
  sol = solve(expr)
  print(f"{sol[0]}")
except:
  print('No tiene solución')
```

Una opción para evitar la asignación multiple tan extensa es creando una función que reciba el rango y el número de elementos a entregar:

```py
def gen_rangos(inicio, fin, veces):
    return [randint(inicio, fin) for _ in range(veces)]
```

y se utilizaría así:

```py
a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z = gen_rangos(1,40, 8)
```

Comment: La primera asignación múltiple la veo un poco engorrosa y creo que una función podría ayudar

Comment: Más o menos cómo?

Comment: edite tu respuesta :D

Comment: Ya la he mirado, muchas gracias, está más compacta y ahorra varias líneas

Comment: bueno ahora que me doy cuenta puedes hacer `a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z  = [randint(1, 40) for _ in range(8)]` lo cual simplifica la llamada a una función

Comment: Ahora me estoy dando cuenta de algo, implementar una condicional en caso de que la ecuación no tenga solución. El programa no puede evaluar -26x - 26(-x + 35) = 10

Comment: si lanza una excepcion puedes usar un `try/except`

Comment: Más bien arroja     `print(f"{sol[0]}")`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: sería cuestión de poner `if not sol: exit("sin solucion")`

Comment: No había leído el comentario, sí, funciona `try/except`, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Añado otra respuesta por que se aleja demasiado a la solución dada en mi anterior respuesta. En la otra daba una solución simple y basada en lo hablado en el chat entre el autor de la pregunta y mi persona. En esta respuesta hablaré del funcionamiento de mi programa diseñado para evaluar expresiones aritméticas, algebraicas o polinómicas a base de un string, hay cosas que aún no están terminadas pero todo ello lo detallaré más adelante (no explicaré todo en detalle ya que sería muy extenso).

En principio mi programa consta de 3 clases que se encargan de distintas funciones o cosas del programa. En primer lugar y que es la base de todo es la clase `Number` la cual crea un objeto de tipo `Number` que aparte de representar un número entero o decimal puede representar exponentes, monomios, etc.

**Código de la clase `Number`**

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from collections import Counter

class Number():
    def __init__(self, num, exp=1, literal_part:list=None, exp_literal:list=None, simple=False):
        self.simple = simple
        self.literal = literal_part if literal_part else []
        self.exp_literal = exp_literal if exp_literal else [1 for _ in range(len(self.literal))] if self.literal else []
        self.base = float(num) if num not in [float, int] else num
        self.exp = float(exp) if exp not in [float, int] else exp
    
    def eval(self)->int:
        return self.base**self.exp

    def __add__(self, other):
        if self.literal==other.literal and self.exp_literal==other.exp_literal:
            return Number(self.eval()+other.eval(), literal_part=self.literal[:], exp_literal=self.exp_literal[:])
        elif [other.exp, self.exp] == [1, 1] and not self.literal:
            return Number(self.base + other.base, literal_part=self.literal)
        else:
            return self, other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if self.literal==other.literal and self.exp_literal==other.exp_literal:
            base = self.eval() - other.eval()
            literal, exp_literal = self.literal, self.exp_literal
            if not base: 
                literal, exp_literal = None, None
            if base>0: base=-base
            return Number(base, literal_part=literal, exp_literal=exp_literal)
        elif [other.exp, self.exp] == [1, 1] and not self.literal:
            base = self.base - other.base
            if base>0: base=-base
            return Number(base, literal_part=literal)
        else:
            return self, other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        exp_literal, literal = self.exp_literal[:], self.literal[:]
        exp, base = self.exp, self.base

        if self.base==other.base:
            exp=self.exp+other.exp
        else:
            base =self.base*other.base

        if self.literal and other.literal:
            for other,exp in zip(other.literal, other.exp_literal):
                if other in self.literal:
                    i = self.literal.index(other)
                    exp_literal[i]+=exp
                else:
                    literal.append(other)
                    exp_literal.append(exp)
        else:
            literal.extend(other.literal)
            exp_literal.extend(other.exp_literal)
        return Number(base, exp, literal[:], exp_literal[:])

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        exp_literal, literal = self.exp_literal[:], self.literal[:]
        exp, base = self.exp, self.base

        if self.base==other.base:
            exp=self.exp-other.exp
        else:
            base =self.base/other.base

        if self.literal and other.literal:
            for other,exp in zip(other.literal, other.exp_literal):
                if other in self.literal:
                    i = self.literal.index(other)
                    self.exp_literal[i]-=exp
                    if not self.exp_literal[i]:
                        self.exp_literal.pop(i)
                        self.literal.pop(i)
                else:
                    self.literal.append(other)
                    self.exp_literal.append(-exp)
        elif other.literal:
            if not self.literal: 
                self.literal,  self.exp_literal = [], []
            self.literal.extend(other.literal)
            self.exp_literal+=[-exp for exp in other.exp_literal]
        return Number(base, exp, self.literal, self.exp_literal)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.base}{f'^{self.exp}' if self.exp>1 else ''}{''.join(f'{letra}^{exp}' for letra,exp in zip(self.literal,self.exp_literal)) if self.literal else ''}"

    def dist(self, number):
        self.exp *=number
        return self
```

La composición de objetos `Number` dan lugar a un nuevo objeto, llamado `AlgExpresion` que se crea al momento de realizar cualquier operación aritmética entre objetos `Number`. Sin embargo la clase que da origen a una `AlgExpresion` es la clase `Expresión` que se encarga de *parsear* al string de entrada, se analiza caracter por caracter, separando cada expresión y operación, cada expresión identificada pasa a ser procesada y convertida a una de tipo `Number` pero antes se reduce toda la base a lo mínimo y queda una operación de potenciación. El primer proceso de *parseo* está a cargo del inicializador (`__init__`) de la clase `Expresion`, el proceso de reducción del número está a cargo de un método llamado `descomponer` que descompone, cada expresión identificada en el `__init__`, en un número más simple con exponente, si el número presenta parte literal también se separa el número de su parte literal para ser analizada, esto es hecho por el método `separate_num`. Si el número es demasiado alto (mayor a las 14 cifras) se utiliza la el módulo `Decimal` para poder tener una mayor precisión al momento de descomponer el número, esto se hace ya que la descomposición se basa en divisiones sucesivas y esto causa errores de aproximación en números mayores a las 14. También el método `descomponer` tiene un pequeño *"sistema de seguridad"* y es que existe el caso en que un número sea primo y este sea un número muy alto, por lo que llegar hasta ese número puede tardar varios minutos, por ello esta función se rompe luego de unas determinadas iteraciones, y se vuelve a repetir unas cuantas veces, si hasta ello no se ha conseguido reducir más el número entonces para y deja el número reducido con lo máximo que se pudo.

Voy dejando un el código de la clase `Expresion` para que se entienda más lo que dije.

**Código de la clase `Expresion`**

```py
class Expresion():
    OPERATORS = "*/+"
    PRECEDENCIA = {
        "*": 2,
        "/": 2,
        "+": 1,
        "-": 1
    }
    def __init__(self, expresion:str):
        expresion = self.process_espresion(expresion)
        self.expresions = []
        self.operations = []
        self.convert = False
        length=len(expresion)
        i = 0

        while i<length:
            inicio = i
            tk = expresion[i]
            if i==0 and tk in "+-": 
                i+=1
                tk = expresion[i]
            while tk.isspace() and i<length-1:
                i+=1
                tk = expresion[i]

            while not tk in "+*/-" and i!=length-1:
                if tk in "()": 
                    i+=1 
                    break
                i+=1
                tk = expresion[i]
                
            if i==length-1: i+=1
            else: 
                self.operations.append(expresion[i])
            res = self.descomponer(expresion[inicio:i])
            self.expresions.append(res)
            i+=1

    def process_espresion(self, expresion:str)->str:
        negative=False
        if not "(" in expresion: return expresion
        n = expresion.index("(")
        expresion=f"{expresion[:n]}{expresion[n+1:]}"
        e=1
        while True:
            if n>=len(expresion): break
            if expresion[n-e]=="-": 
                negative=True

            if negative:
                if expresion[n]=="+":
                    expresion=f"{expresion[:n]}-{expresion[n+1:]}"
                elif expresion[n]=="-":
                    expresion=f"{expresion[:n]}+{expresion[n+1:]}"
                elif expresion[n]==")":
                    negative=False
                    expresion=f"{expresion[:n]}{expresion[n+1:]}"
                    continue
            n+=1
        #el ultimo replace es debido un pequeño bug 
        #que descubrí mientras escribbia la respuesta
        return expresion.replace(")","").replace("-+","-")

    def separate_num(self, num):
        nums,i = "", 0
        for c in num:
            if not c: continue
            elif c in "0123456789.+-*/": i+=1
            else: break
        return num[:i], num[i:].strip()

    def descomponer(self, expresion:str)->tuple:
        literal, negative = None, None
        expresion=expresion.strip()
        num, exp = expresion.split("^") if "^" in expresion else (expresion,1)
        try:
            num_proc = float(num) if len(num)<=14 else Decimal(num)
        except:
            num, literal = self.separate_num(num)
            if not num: num="1"
            num_proc = float(num) if len(num)<=14 else Decimal(num)
            return {num_proc:1}, float(exp), literal
        if num_proc ==1.0:
            return {1:1},1, literal
        elif num_proc<0:
            num_proc = abs(num_proc)
            negative=True
        pot, r = 2, 1
        div = []
        while num_proc>0:
            if not num_proc%pot:
                if negative: 
                    pot =-pot
                    negative=False
                div+=[pot]
                num_proc/=pot
                continue
            else: 
                pot+=1
                if pot >50000: 
                    pot=2
                    r +=1
                    if r>3: 
                        div+=[num_proc]
                        break
                if num_proc == 1.0: break
        return Counter(div), float(exp), literal

    def _convert_number(self):
        i=0
        res = []
        for num, pot, literal in self.expresions:
            operations =[]
            itms = num.items()
            res += [Number(n, exp).dist(pot) for n,exp in itms]
            if literal: 
                res[-1].literal=[literal]
                res[-1].exp_literal=[1]

            if len(itms): operations+=["*"]*(len(itms)-1)
            for op in operations:
                self.operations.insert(i, op)
            i+=len(operations)+1

        res[0] = AlgExpresion([res[0]])
        self.expresions = res[:]
        self.convert = True

    def operar(self, reduce=True):
        operaciones = {
            "+":lambda x,y: x + y,
            "-": lambda x,y: x - y,
            "*": lambda x,y: x * y
        } 

        prece = Expresion.PRECEDENCIA
        while len(self.operations)>=2 and len(self.expresions)>=2:
            op1, op2 = self.operations[:2]

            if prece[op1]>=prece[op2]:
                res = operaciones[op1](*self.expresions[:2])
                i=0
            else:
                res = operaciones[op2](*self.expresions[1:3])
                i=1
            self.operations.pop(i)
            del self.expresions[i:2+i]
            self.expresions.insert(i, res)
        else:
            res = operaciones[self.operations.pop(0)](*self.expresions)
            self.expresions = res
        return self
    
    
    def compile(self):
        if not self.convert: self._convert_number()
        return self

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if type(other)!=Expresion: raise ValueError(f"No se puede operar con un objeto de tipo {type(other)}")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        if not self.convert:
            expresion = ""
            for i in range(len(self.operations)):
                expresion += f"{self.expresions[i]} {self.operations[i]} "
            expresion += f"{self.expresions[-1]}"
            return expresion
        else: return repr(self.expresions)
```

Lo que retorna el método `descomponer` es una tupla de 3 elementos, que contiene como primer elemento un diccionario un objeto `Counter` que contiene la descomposición del número en forma `{base: exponente}`, el segundo elemento es el exponente real del número por ejemplo, `4^3` la descomposición de `4` resulta en `2^2` pero todo ello va elevado al cubo (`3`) y  el tercer elemento es la parte literal del número, si no tiene parte literal se retorna `None`. Sin embargo nunca se opera con el diccionario sino, como dije, se opoera con objetos `Number` por lo que creé un método llamado `compile` que se encarga de ejecutar las funciones necesarias para poder convertir esa tupla de 3 elementos en un objeto `Number`, ese método debe ser llamado al momento de ejecutar el código, pues la base para iniciar la operación. Para operar o resolver la expresión dada en string se llama al método `.operar` este método se encarga de realizar las operaciones incluso tiene en cuenta la precedencia de operadores, todas las operaciones son implementadas desde 0.

Para ayudar a este método se han implementado los *dunder methods* de la clase `Number` y de la clase `AlgExpresion`. Al realizar la primera operación se hace entre objetod de tipo `Number` y `Number` pero el resultado de eso es un objeto `AlgExpresion` por lo que las suiguientes operaciones (ocurriendo en precedencia normal, osea de mayor a menor precedencia) se realizan entre `AlgExpresion` y `Number`.

**Código de la clase `AlgExpresion`**

```py
class AlgExpresion():
    def __init__(self, expresion:list):
        self.terminos = expresion.copy()
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        include=None
        terms = self.terminos[:]
        for i,term in enumerate(self.terminos):
            if term.literal == other.literal:
                terms[i] = term+other
                include=True
                break
            else: include=False
        if not include:
            terms.append(other)
        return AlgExpresion(terms)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        include=None
        terms = self.terminos[:]
        for i,term in enumerate(self.terminos):
            if term.literal == other.literal:
                terms[i] = term-other
                include=True
                break
            else: include=False
        if not include:
            if other.base>0:
                other.base = -other.base
            terms.append(other)
        return AlgExpresion(terms)
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        terms = self.terminos[:]
        terms[-1]*=other
        return AlgExpresion(terms)
    
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        terms = self.terminos[:]
        terms[-1]/=other
        return AlgExpresion(terms)
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.terminos[item]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "+".join(str(term) for term in self.terminos).replace("+-","-")
```

Con estas 3 clases practicamene ya está resuelto todo. El orden para colocar las clases es: primero clase `Number`, segundo clase `AlgExpresion` y por último la clase `Expresion`

Todas las clases tienen implementado el *dunder method* `__repr__` para ser mostradas de forma *"bonita"*.

Ahora te doy unos ejemplos de uso:

```py
ex1 = Expresion("6a*2a-3+1").compile()
print(ex1.operar(), end="\n")

ex2 = Expresion("-31x+4*x*2+1").compile()
print(ex2.operar())
```

Dando como resultado:

```
12.0a^2-2.0

-23.0x^1+1.0
```

Esto se puede aplicar de forma muy fácil a tu proyecto, teniendo en cuenta mi respuesta anterior:

```py
from random import randint, choice

#podemos borrar los 1 en las x
fmts = {'-{}x - (-{} - x) = {}' : '-{}x - (-{} - x) - {}'} 
view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)

expr = expr.format(x,y,z)
#almacenaremos la expresión en forma de igualdad
view_expr = view_expr.format(x,y,z)

#recomiendo eliminar espacios en blanco para correcto funcionamiento
ex = Expresion(expr.replace(" ","")).compile()
resultado = ex.operar()
print(f"{expr} = {resultado}")
```

Que dará como resultado (en mi caso):

```
-25x - (-36 - 1x) - 5 = -24.0x^1-31.0
```

Lo cual no está mal algebraicamente, pero obviamente no es el mismo resultado que entrega `sympy`, pues mi programa no puede evaluar igualdades y tampoco despeja variables, si lo que quieres es despejar `x` puedes hacer algo como:

```py
var, num = resultado.expresions[:]
literal_part = var.literal[0]
res = f"{literal_part} = {num.base/var.base}"
print(res)
```

Que según las varaibles anteriores (misma ejecución) da como resultado:

```
x = 1.2916666666666667
```

Esto solo funciona para casos como el anterior, teniendo solo una variable y que ambos números no tenga exponente, de lo contrario se tendrían que convertir a tipo `Number` nuevamente (el que tiene parte literal)  y operar.

Más que nada espero que esto te sirva para que sepas como funcionan las cosas además que refuerzas conocimientos matemáticos :D, esto aún presenta algunos *bugs* o falta de funcionalidades, como es la multiplicacion a un grupo de expresiones agrupadas mediante paréntesis, como lo es el siguiente caso `2*(x+3)` esto no está implementado, al igual que las expresiones con parte literal que tengan exponente, poner `Expresion("2a^2+3")` dará algún error pues este tipo de entrada no esta soportada (pero como parte de operaciones o salida sí). Si tienes alguna duda puedes hacermela y con gusto resonderé :D.