# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar instancias de un carácter en un string en python?

Tags: python

En base a la pregunta de [¿Cómo puedo evaluar una ecuación de primer grado que contenga paréntesis?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/508399/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evaluar-una-ecuaci%C3%B3n-de-primer-grado-que-contenga-par%C3%A9ntesis/508839?noredirect=1#comment903858_508839) trato de reemplazar las instancias de un carácter que imprime un string de manera estética.

El programa me arroja `-1x/-25 - 4 = -16x/-25 - 2` y trato de reemplazar el `1x` únicamente por la expresión `x`, de tal manera que me quede: `-x/-25 - 4 = -16x/-25 - 2`

Para reemplazarlo, realizo lo siguiente:

```
reemplazar = view_expr.replace('1x', 'x')
raw_expr = expr
```

Esto funciona bien, pero el problema es que al imprimir valores aleatorios del 1 al 100, la expresión puede tomar valores como `11x, 21x, 31x, 41x, 51x, 61x, 71x, 81x, 91x` y cuando se reemplazan queda `1x, 2x, 3x, 4x, 5x, 6x, 7x, 8x, 9x`.
¿Hay alguna forma de resolver este problema? De ante mano agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: podrías usar una expresión regular

Comment: jajajajajaja, ya no por favor

Comment: El ejercicio se basa de por sí en puras expresiones regulares

Comment: Bueno la segunda opción es separar el replace, es decir guardar una copia del string en una variable y solo aplicar `.replace("x","1x")` y al momento de mostrar la operación usas la otra vriable

Comment: en base a mi respuesta anterior deberías de eliminar los 1 que pones en el diccionario y hacer `expr = expr.replace("x","1*x")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a mi [respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/508817/183782) podemos optar por otra solución mediante `replace` ya que no quieres usar expresiones regulares.

Al se tiene el valor de forma `-{}x - (-{} - 1x) - {}` ya que las variables necesitan tener coeficiente para que pueda funcionar mi solución, pero tu requieres que al momento de imprimirlo no salga ese `1` que he añadido. Entonces podemos modificar el valor del diccionario y regresarlo a como lo tenías en un comienzo `-{}x - (-{} - x) - {}` pero ahora haremos esto:

```py
#reemplazamos por una multiplicación
expr = expr.replace("x","1*x") #agregamos el 1
```

Añadimos el `1` al string que será operado con `eval` y no al otro que será mostrado, con eso ya es suficiente.

Aquí te dejo el código completo

```py
view_expr, expr = choice(list(fmts.items()))
w,x,y,z = randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40), randint(1,40)

#almacenamos la expresión para ser evaluada con sympy
expr = expr.format(w,x,y,z)
#almacenaremos la expresión en forma de igualdad
view_expr = view_expr.format(w,x,y,z)

#reemplazamos por una multiplicación
expr = expr.replace("x","1*x") #aquí añadimos el 1
x = symbols('x')

#evaluamos
eq1 = Eq(eval(expr,{"x":x}), 0)
sol = solve(expr)
print(view_expr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pareciera el tuyo, ser un buen ejemplo para aplicar expresiones regulares:

```
import re
view_expr = "ejemplos 1x 11x -1x 11y 1y 1z"
view_expr = re.sub(r'\b1([A-Za-z])\b', r'\\1', view_expr)
print(view_expr)

ejemplos x 11x -x 11y y z
```

Básicamente, el patrón `\b1([A-Za-z])\b'` captura la letra después del `1` siempre que ambos caracteres estén encerrados en patrones considerados "word boundaries", la letra se captura y se usa en el reemplazo, de esta forma podemos tener una solución más general y no solo aplicada a la variable `x`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me parece bastante eficiente no solo para una variable, sino generalizada como lo comentas