# Función Factorizar numero y devuelva sus factores y sus exponentes en Python:

Tags: python, lista, factorial

Mi problema en esta función es que tengo que devolver los factores y los exponentes en dos listas, pero al momento de devolverme los exponentes me devuelve algo que no es, ya que el 2 se repite 2 veces pero el 3 solo una y no logro encontrar el error

```
def factorizarnumero(numero):
    encontrar_primo = []
    primos_repetidos = []

    for i in range(2, numero+1):
        while numero % i == 0:
            encontrar_primo.append(i)
            numero = numero / i
    for e in encontrar_primo:
        if encontrar_primo.count(e) >= 2:
            primos_repetidos.append(e)

    return sorted((list(set(encontrar_primo)))), primos_repetidos

    print(factorizarnumero(12))
    #Resultado:
    ([2,3], [2,2])
```

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509464/183782) creo una clase `Number` para poder procesar expresiones aritméticas. En una parte del código se implementa la factorización. Puede usar ese código.

Comment: Gracias! Pero no logro entender en que parte del código que me envio se encuentra lo relacionado a esta pregunta

Comment: En la clase `Expresion` en el método `descomponer` desde la parte del `while`

Answer (score 1):

No cuento con amplia experiencia en Python, pero leyendo la documentación me pude dar cuenta de lo siguiente:

La función `count()` devuelve cuántas veces (recuento) aparece un objeto en una lista; es decir, que requiere de un objeto list para poder cumplir su función, es ahí donde viene el primer error. En el segundo `for...in` deberías de pasar una lista pero con los elementos únicos. Así, quedaría el código de la siguiente forma:

```
def factorizarnumero(numero):
    encontrar_primo = []
    primos_repetidos = []

    for i in range(2, numero+1):
        while numero % i == 0:
            encontrar_primo.append(i)
            numero = numero / i

    for e in list(set(encontrar_primo)):
        if encontrar_primo.count(e) >= 2:
            primos_repetidos.append(e)
        else:
            primos_repetidos.append(0)

    return sorted((list(set(encontrar_primo)))), primos_repetidos
```

El output quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```py
print(factorizarnumero(12))

# salida:
([2, 3], [2, 0])
```

> **Nota:** Agregué en el `for...in` la parte del `else` para que agregue al array un cero (0) en caso no encuentre nada, eso puedes borrarlo si no desees que se muestre así.

Comment: Podrías explicar esto `[...] estas pasando un array y no una lista.`?? En python no existen los array (a menos que trabajes con numpy, en cuyo caso será un nparray).

Comment: Como dije, no tengo experiencia (casi nada) en Python, pero al hacer uso de `list(set(array))` el `count` trabaja de forma correcta; en todo caso solo fuera un error de conceptos, modificaré la respuesta.

Comment: Pues sí, tienes un error de concepto y lo puedes comprobar. `type([])`  mostrará `List` pues es una lista. Las listas puedes crearlas de 2 formas, haciendo uso de los corchetes `lista = []` o haciendo uso del constructor `lista = list()`

Comment: Listo, editado. Igualmente, gracias por la ilustración compañero.

Comment: Chicos! Gracias por sus respuesta, en parte me ayudaron! gracias!